# Do acausal quantum events come in between two classical events?

Tags: determinism, quantum-physics, causality

You'll have to forgive my ignorance if the answer to this question has lots of examples of how and when this occurs.

My knowledge of determinism is that it is a picture of a chain of events that goes back temporally and will also go forward temporally.

We observe events at the classical level and it is proposed that these events are causal, however, there are events that occur at a level that it is difficult to observe, the quantum level, it is proposed that the outcome of these events are acausal.

My question is.

Are there examples of when an acausal quantum event comes in between two causal classical events that will break this temporal chain of causality and invalidate classical determinism ?

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, there is no such thing as a classical determinist world juxtaposed with a quantic non-determinist world. That would be a schizophrenic universe.

The world is coherent. It's one world, not two different worlds ruled by two different gods, one quantic and the other one classical. The scale (micro vs macro) that supposedly separate those two worlds is in the eye of the beholder, when one zooms in or zooms out the picture.

If one zooms in, one can see the pixels composing the picture, and the pixels look quite different from the overall picture, but the difference is only one of scale. The pixels do not belong to another world than the picture. Rather, they compose the picture.

Ergo, there's no such thing as a "classical event" or a "quantum event". There are events, which we model through different scientific theories. Some theories are called "classical" and other "quantum".

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly imagine such random links in the chain of causation. Suppose I decide what route to follow through a city by stopping at every junction and using a Geiger counter and a weak radio-active source to determine at random which way to turn.  When I am driving between junctions,  classical cause and effect seems to be taking place, but when I reach a junction quantum indeterminism decides which way I go, thus breaking the chain of classical causality. Practically I could achieve pretty much the same effect by tossing a coin at each junction, so I am not sure why quantum indeterminacy, per se, adds much.

Answer (score 0):

No, and here is why.

To begin with, the classical and quantum realms are separated by a vast difference in *distance scales*. the distance scale for the quantum world is ~smaller than an atom and for classical events it is ~anything bigger than an amoeba. What this means is that there is nothing that a single quantum event can do to affect the trajectory of a billiard ball as it caroms around a table. So the causal chain of a cue ball is independent of the quantum state of any particular atom contained in it.

Now note that the behavior of a quantum system like the radioactive decay occurring in a chunk of uranium is *probabilistic* when you are looking at any individual atomic nucleus; it only makes *deterministic* sense when looking at a large ensemble for which, in this example, a well-defined average *half-life* can be measured.

Comment: @neils nielsen Radioactice decay of a nuclei is caused by that nucleus being unstable, and the emmision of a particle reduces the overall energy of the nucleus and it becomes more stable. I have read that the formation of unstable nuclei can occur in the lab and in nature, such as in nuclear fusion. So is this a causal chain, the cause of unstable nuclei from nuclear fusion and the formation of a stable nuclei caused by radioactive decay? I proposed that quantum events are acausal. however, it would appear that they are not? I understand the precise time of these events remains indeterminable.